# javascript regular expression to replace special characters, but allow a whitelist, using xregexp

Tags: javascript, regex, xregexp

I want to replace most special characters from a string (in javascript), but allow some special cases, like c++, c# and more. I have experimented with the xregexp library in node.js and I am able to remove all non letters and numbers, I think. I would also like to allow all foreign language letters. This is what I have so far:

```
  var str = "I do programming in c++ and sometimes c#, but + and # should be removed";
  regex = XRegExp('[^\\s\\p{N}\\p{L}]+', 'g');
  var replaced = XRegExp.replace(str, regex, "");
  console.log(replaced);
```

This outputs

```
I do programming in c and sometimes c, but and should be removed
```

I need to create some kind of list with allowed words, like c++ and c#. Desired output is:

```
I do programming in c++ and sometimes c#, but and should be removed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use alternations inside a capturing group and then restore this text with a backreference in the replacement pattern:

```js
var str = "I do programming in c++ and sometimes c#, but + and # should be removed";
regex = XRegExp('(\\b(?:c[+]{2}|c#)(?!\\w))|[^\\s\\p{N}\\p{L}]+', 'ig');
//               ^-- capture group 1 -----^                        ^  
var replaced = XRegExp.replace(str, regex, "$1");
//                                          ^^
console.log(replaced);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/2.0.0/xregexp-all-min.js"></script>
```

Note I added an `i` flag to make the pattern case insensitive, `\b` in the beginning of the alternations to only match at the word boundary (since `c++` and `c#` start with a letter (word character), and the lookahead `(?!\w)` that makes sure there is no word character after `+` and `#` (`\b` would not work here as these are not word characters).

Comment: Actually, it also removes commas (you provided a wrong current output). I suppose you also need to add `\\p{P}` to your negated character class.

Comment: This works perfectly, sorry about the wrong output, commas should be removed, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I'm having some trouble modifying this to also not replace .NET, could you give an example of this as well?

Comment: `regex = XRegExp('(\\B\\.NET\\b|\\b(?:c[+]{2}|c#)(?!\\w))|[^\\s\\p{N}\\p{L}]+', 'ig');`